Retrieve all terminal service attributes of a AD user
Am currently using WTSQueryUserConfig to retrieve AD user's all terminal service attributes like
"tsIntialProgram", "tsWorkingDir", "tsInheritInitialProgram","tsAllowLogon", "tsTimeOutSettingsConnections", "tsTimeOutSettingsDisConnections", "tsShadowSettings","tsServerRemoteHomeDir",....
But it is taking lot of time for just hundreds of users.
Seems all terminal service attributes info are stored in userParameters AD attribute, and since it is encoded, not in a readable form. If there is any c++ API that parses all terminal service attributes info present in that attribute and returns in a readable form would be great.
What is the fastest way to retrieve all terminal service attributes of AD users using LDAP C++? Any other API is there? (Interested only in C++, not Powershell or other languages)

It seems that the NetpParmsQueryUserProperty() function from netapi32.dll can parse the property string, as can UsrPropGetValue() from regapi.dll.
NTSTATUS
NetpParmsQueryUserProperty (
    IN  LPWSTR          UserParms,
    IN  LPWSTR          PropertyName,
    OUT PWCHAR          PropertyFlag,
    OUT PUNICODE_STRING PropertyValue
    );

NTSTATUS
NetpParmsQueryUserPropertyWithLength (
    IN  PUNICODE_STRING UserParms,
    IN  LPWSTR          PropertyName,
    OUT PWCHAR          PropertyFlag,
    OUT PUNICODE_STRING PropertyValue
    );

NTSTATUS
UsrPropGetValue(
    TCHAR *pValueName,
    PVOID pValue,
    ULONG ValueLength,
    WCHAR *pUserParms
    );

Although the value from LDAP appears to be a binary blob, it actually has to be decoded as a UTF-8 string into a wchar array first, and from there it is a fairly simple list of structs (thanks MS for still keeping the Microsoft Windows source code up on Microsoft GitHub) – though confusingly the lengths are in bytes (not in wchar units), and while the name is stored as a wchar[length/2], the property value has to be cast back to char[] where it turns out to be a hex-encoded ASCII string... but I managed to parse it from Python, so it should be even simpler to do it from C++.
The whole thing appears to be a relic from Novell NetWare era in early 1990s, which might explain its crustiness.

hi thanks for the response.. i have included netapi32.lib dependency in my project, but still NetpParmsQueryUserProperty identifier not found error is coming.. i tried including lmaccess.h header file.. still same error.. may be i should include some other header file.. searched regarding this, but unable to get info. kindly assist.

Best I could find, they are all kind-of sort-of internal functions, so if you don't find them in system headers, try copying the C function declaration from my post directly into your code and see if the linking succeeds after build. But I would rather write an own parser in C++, it's a slightly wacky but overall simple format (and hasn't changed since early 1990s, so probably won't be changing in the future either).
